# Safari does not set cookie but Chrome and Firefox do

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I'm sending requests from the localhost to third party server to get data using REST API.
Backend uses cookies ("JSESSIONID") to understand either send data or not.
All works fine in Chrome, and I can see Cookies in the Application tab of the Chrome browser, with some data. But this specific key ("JSESSIONID") is not set as a value.
Meanwhile in Safari Cookies tab does not contain any value, but I can see this line in Response:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FE833C57BF6448BBF12036948C337372A2CFD793F3C7.devOrderEntry; Path=/orderEntry; HttpOnly
```

In the same time, the backend is waiting for the Cookie with this param from the client, and this param is empty in Safari's header.

I use axios for XMLHttpRequests, and webpack as builder.
I tried several things such as withCredentials: true, or set 'max-length' for 1 year, but it did not worked.
Please advice something!

This is how it works in Firefox:

[image: This is how it works in Firefox]

And in Safari:

[image: This is how it works in Safari]

Comment: Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy -> Prevent cross-site tracking.
This checkbox has to be turned off. Anyway, when user is involved to the browser settings to fetch data, it's a wrong way. Any idea?

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this? I have this problem as well, primarily on iOS Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It looks like it's a specific settings of Safari browser.

Comment: related question for those looking for answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56972162/2544629