# Session Variables getting reset in Mac

Tags: session, asp-classic

I have a search form in classic ASP. I used sessions to store search variables. The search is working perfectly in Chrome, session is stored with search variables. But the session is getting reset in Safari. Is this an issue with mac or the browser safari?

Comment: Are you really using "Classic ASP" (the really old technology, with spaghetti-code style VBA) - or are you using **ASP.NET** (with C# or VB.NET) ?? Those are **not** the same - please clean up your tags accordingly!

Comment: If you are using Classic ASP check that Safari is not blocking the session cookies. This might be relevant - [Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144894), [Safari does not set cookie but Chrome and Firefox do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53082080) and [Safari isn't saving cookies, but Chrome is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44318960).